# Sending mail in php

Tags: php, sendmail

Here i am new to PHP, i want to send the mail and my application is running on go daddy sahre hosting so please tell me hows can i achieve it . 
thanks to all.

I got the response from you guys and I tried but there is some problem .
this is my code ..

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Send Mail</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
        if( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['msg']) )
        {
            $to = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $msg = $_POST['msg'];
            $from = "abhisheks.net@gmail.com";
            $headers = "From: $from";
            mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
            echo "Mail Send";
        }

 ?>
 <form action="sendMail.php" method="post">

 <div>
 <table style="width:100%;">
 <tr>
 <td>Email:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
 <td>Subject:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Message</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="msg" /></td>
 <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" value="Send Mail" /></td>

 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And after running this page i got the error

```
"Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 554 The message was rejected because it contains prohibited virus or spam content in D:\Hosting\5676400\html\myPhp\temp\admin\sendMail.php on line 17"
```

Comment: www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The PHP mail() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mail.asp)

Basic Example:

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From: $from";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks to reply , i tried your code but i got the error message, here i am editing the my question , i am putting my code and also the error message please see what is the problem in that. thanks once again.

Comment: I think you have to provide some SMTP settings. I posted very basic example. You have to provide some more information according to your server settings. Look at these: **1.** http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10367822 **2.** http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm **3.** http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=28584

Answer (score 4):

Naveed's answer is all that is required for sending a basic email.

**For reference:**

PHP's Mail function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

**Commonly used classes providing additional functionality:**

PHPMailer - http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Zend_Mail - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html

Answer (score 2):

See a good example for sending emails here

http://thinkspacetechnologies.com/blog/sending-mails-via-php-script-2/

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$message="hi";
$to="to@exmaple.com";
$sub='Subject of the Mail';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:from@example.com\r\n";
mail($to,$sub,$message,$headers); 
?>
```

simple Mail sending in php

this will accept the html tags and perform accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Beware that while the PHP `mail()` function is pretty simple and convenient to use, the computer OS must be able to send mail by itself.

You have to check the return value of `mail()` (boolean, *true* if mail was accepted for delivery).

```
  $result = mail( ... );
```

If the `$result` variable is *false*, you have to check your computer mail configuration/implementation.

If it is *true*, and the mail is not sent, you have to check the computer mail logs.