# replying to email address on the from

Tags: php, webforms

here's the process.php. I want to receive the email from the email address on the form so I could reply to them

```
<?php

$where_form_is="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].strrev(strstr(strrev($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"/"));

 // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";
    $headers .= "From: " .  $_POST['field_9'] . "\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $_POST['field_9'] . "\n";

mail("harshad@madiganpratt.com","Reservaion Enquiry","Form data:


Preferred Arrival Date : " . $_POST['field_1'] . " 
Preferred Departure Date: " . $_POST['field_2'] . " 
Room Category: " . $_POST['field_3'] . " 
Adults: " . $_POST['field_4'] . " 
Children: " . $_POST['field_5'] . " 
Please contact me by: " . $_POST['field_6'] . " 
First Name: " . $_POST['field_7'] . " 
Last Name: " . $_POST['field_8'] . " 
Email: " . $_POST['field_9'] . " 
Phone: " . $_POST['field_10'] . " 

");

include("confirm.html");

?>
```

......

Comment: What's the problem? What errors are you getting? Where does the input come from?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the headers:

```
            // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";
        $headers .= "From: " .  $from . "\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\n";
        $headers .= "CC: email@eami.com\n"; 

        // Mail it
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\n"; 



should .$from be field_9

Comment: Yes it should be `$_POST['field_9']`

Comment: $headers .= "From: " .  $_POST['field_9'] . "\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $_POST['field_9'] . "\n";

 Something wrong..i am not receiving any mails

Comment: You'll need to edit your original question above and add your new code.

Comment: <?php

$where_form_is="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].strrev(strstr(strrev($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"/"));

     // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";
        $headers .= "From: " .  $_POST['field_9'] . "\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $_POST['field_9'] . "\n";

mail("harshad@madiganpratt.com","Reservaion Enquiry","Form data:

THis is where i added it.

Comment: Please add it to your original question with proper indentation. I don't want to read that mess

Comment: You have a few problems. I recommend you take a look at this tread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714558/sending-mail-in-php